# RestSharp Deserialization of empty string to Dictionary Error

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

I'm a bit new to RestSharp so please excuse my ignorance.  I'm getting the following error:

```
 {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."}
```

This happens when RestSharp tries to deserialize and empty string to a Dictionary object.

Here is the my abbreviated Result object:

```
public class Result
{
     public Dictionary<string, string> assignment_group { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what is returned if assignment_group is populated:

```
"assignment_group":{"link":"https://someurl/api/now/table/sys_user_group/2c1cf1176f29f5007a3db03f5d3ee4aa","value":"2c1cf1176f29f5007a3db03f5d3ee4aa"}
```

Here is what is returned if assignment_group is not populated:

```
"assignment_group":""
```

What is happening is the JSON response for assignment_group will be a Dictionary or an empty string.  I will only get the error if it's an empty string.  How can I accommodate both return types in my Result class assignment_group property?

Thanks in advance for any help out there.

**Update:**
Here is working solution for me.

Instead of default Deserializer used by RestSharp, I used Newtonsoft.Json instead.   Here is code example from my wrapper class:

```
 public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
 {
        if (request.Method == Method.POST)
            client.FollowRedirects = false;

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        // **** Added Newtonsoft.Json ****
        var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content);


        LogRequest(request, client);
        LogResponse<T>(response);

        ErrorHandling<T>(response);

       //  ****This is no longer needed. Data is null now****
       // return response.Data;  

       //  **** Added **** 
       return x;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you making use of a custom serializer/deserializer for this? Because my understanding is that the following cases are covered (but your example is not):

1. assignment_group = null;
   results in "assignment_group":null
2. assignment_group = new Dictionary();
   results in "assignment_group" : "{}"
3. assignment_group = new Dictionary(); assignment_group.Add("key","value");
   results in "assignment_group" : "{"key":"value"}

This may also be related to: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/486

Comment: If the API that I'm consuming returned at {} for an empty Dictionary then everything would be good.  Unfortunately it is returning "".  Now I'm assuming RestSharp cannot deserialze this to Dictionary out of the box and will need a custom deserializer?

Comment: From that bug issue described there that seems to be what's needed.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffrey for leading me down the right path :)  I'm now using the Newtonsoft.Json for my serializer/deserializer and it seems to resolve this problem I'm having.

Comment: Hmm. I might of jumped the gun a bit earlier.  I'm still getting same error with Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: My bad.. Newtonsoft works..  There was an issue with the data being serialized.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a code post of what calls are actually producing the JSON that is erroneous?