# How Do I Use a RestResponse for a List<class> return?

Tags: restsharp

First, thank you for all of your help - I am constantly on the site looking for answers and they are here more times than not!

Right now I am receiving the following error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."

When attempting to run the following code:

```
            var clientX = new RestClient(_context.CloudUrl + ":" + _context.CloudPort.ToString());
            clientX.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
            var requestX = new RestRequest("/api/web/GetAllDevicePolicies", Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);

            IRestResponse<List<DevicePolicy>> devicePolicies = clientX.Execute<List<DevicePolicy>>(requestX);
```

I can run the command in a browser and I have verified that the returned JSON looks correct - I even validated it through an online validation tool and it provides this:

```html
[{
 "id": "5be3c6802a78549350d297b0",
 "policyID": 1,
 "policyName": "CloudServer",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how cloud server agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 0,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c7508b829e9abc90d4a6",
 "policyID": 2,
 "policyName": "WindowsServer",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Windows server agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 0,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c7728b829e9abc90d4a7",
 "policyID": 3,
 "policyName": "LinuxServer",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Linux server agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 1,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c79b8b829e9abc90d4a8",
 "policyID": 4,
 "policyName": "IoTDevice",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Linux server agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 2,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c7b08b829e9abc90d4a9",
 "policyID": 5,
 "policyName": "Windows Laptop",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Linux server agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 0,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c7cd8b829e9abc90d4aa",
 "policyID": 6,
 "policyName": "Android Phone",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Android Phone agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 0,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c7f28b829e9abc90d4ab",
 "policyID": 7,
 "policyName": "Linux Laptop",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Linux Laptop agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 1,
 "policyStatus": 2
}, {
 "id": "5be3c80a8b829e9abc90d4ac",
 "policyID": 8,
 "policyName": "Windows Phone",
 "policyDesc": "Controls how Windows Phone agents operate",
 "policyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "policyAuth": "Diffie-Helman",
 "deployedLocations": null,
 "alertResp": 1,
 "policyStatus": 2
}]
```

I have no idea what I am missing and I was really hoping somebody could provide some help.

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure the answer of your service is a json object and not a json string? Both will be validated by a json validator. Can you provide a raw response from a tool like wireshark or fiddler

Comment: Turns out the RestSharp deserializer does not handle nested arrays so well - people apparently use NewtonSoft to get around the issue.

Comment: It's Diffie-Hellman btw, not Helman, but unlikely to be relevant to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this answer in another topic - [RestSharp Deserialization of empty string to Dictionary Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714600/restsharp-deserialization-of-empty-string-to-dictionary-error)

Based on that, I added NewtonSoft.Json and then this code:

```
var clientX = new RestClient(_context.CloudUrl + ":" + _context.CloudPort.ToString());
            clientX.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
            var requestX = new RestRequest("/api/web/GetAllDevicePolicies", Method.GET, DataFormat.Json);

            var response = clientX.Execute<DevicePolicy>(requestX);
            List<DevicePolicy> devicePolicies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DevicePolicy>>(response.Content);
```

That did the trick!

Comment: I just did a test locally with a rest service (aspnet core api) generating a correct json object and your original code is working as expected with restsharp 106.5.4. As I mentionned in my comment on your question, I think your webservice is generating a string and not a json object.

Comment: You might be right but I do not know how to force the web service to generate a JSON object - is their an attribute I am missing?